# Joomla. How to set any module/image to specific position?

Tags: css, facebook, joomla, module, position

I'm using Joomla 1.5 and free template. How do I set any component/image to a specific location?

For now I can use only pre-defined positions (left, right, top... etc)

I downloaded a module "Facebook like box" and I want display it at then top of the page on the right side. I don't know how to create css for a module or what I need to do If I want to create custom position.

Thank you for answers.

Answer (score 0):

I think u should read up a little before starting.check this link.follow instructions for joomla 1.5.

http://docs.joomla.org/How_do_you_add_a_new_module_position%3F

http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=480&t=206206&start=60

Comment: I know that, but I that way I can't place to andmodule to any location of website.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to first define a position with in the template file  index.php , using this   . Then from back-end create this image facebook  module and select the create position .